# Reload page after click ok button in jquery alert

Tags: jquery, alert, pageload, bootbox

Following link is the example of which is am faced as issue. I should reload the page when i click ok button. Unless the page should not be reload. I have google for this. Still no result. How to achieve this.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muthuvikki/nnvx6w6w/2/)

```
 $(function () {
bootbox.alert({
    message: "I'm the first!"
});
location.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't actually read the documentation: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    bootbox.alert({
    message: "I'm the first!",
    callback: function () { location.reload(true); }
});
```